# Спойлер для таблицы JS

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Kак можно реализовать открытие и закрытие данных в таблице по нажатию на ячейку названия таблицы (Microsoft Office и Apple Store)?

Чтобы по нажатию на ячейку с названием изначально была закрыта информация под ней, и так же открывалась по следующему нажатию.

Как можно реализовать открытие и закрытие информации под шапкой для каждой таблицы?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="bjsfull.js"></script>

<body>
  <table id="users_list">
    <tr>
      <td class="no-padding">
        <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" v-bind:id=" 'tblTeam' + indexteam" class="tblTeam">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th class="title_team" style=" font-size:14pt !important; padding: 20px 20px !important; background-color: #002C5E !important; color:white"><i class="fa fa-users" aria-hidden="true"></i> &nbsp;Microsoft Office
              </th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td class="no-padding">
                <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="tblGroup" style="background: cornflowerblue;">
                  <thead>
                    <tr for="spoiler2">
                      <th class="spoiler">
                        <i class="fa fa-folder-open" aria-hidden="true"></i>Developer Team 1
                      </th>
                    </tr>
                  </thead>
                  <tbody>
                    <tr>
                      <td style="width: 50px; ">
                        <img src="/static/assets/green_avatar.svg" alt="" width="36" height="36"><span class="icon_selected"></span></td>
                      <td style="width: 200px">John Sina</td>
                      <td>johnsinaitspower@gmail.com</td>
                      <td style="width: 200px; padding-right: 24px;" class="text-right">+79837164834</td>
                    </tr>
                  </tbody>
                </table>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
        <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" v-bind:id=" 'tblTeam' + indexteam" class="tblTeam">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th class="title_team" style=" font-size:14pt !important; padding: 20px 20px !important; background-color: #002C5E !important; color:white"><i class="fa fa-users" aria-hidden="true"></i> &nbsp;Apple Store
              </th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <br>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td class="no-padding">
                <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="tblGroup" style="background: cornflowerblue;">
                  <thead>
                    <tr for="spoiler2">
                      <th class="spoiler">
                        <i class="fa fa-folder-open" aria-hidden="true"></i>Developer Team 2
                      </th>
                    </tr>
                  </thead>
                  <tbody>
                    <tr>
                      <td style="width: 50px; ">
                        <img src="/static/assets/green_avatar.svg" alt="" width="36" height="36"><span class="icon_selected"></span></td>
                      <td style="width: 200px">John Sina</td>
                      <td>johnsinaitspower@gmail.com</td>
                      <td style="width: 200px; padding-right: 24px;" class="text-right">+79837164834</td>
                    </tr>
                  </tbody>
                </table>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>
```

Comment: Ну, во первых, откажитесь от табличной верстки.
 Если захотите спросить почему - спросите сначала гугл.
Во вторых - просто дайте контенту, который хотите прятать, аттрибут `display:none`(вашим `tbody`), а при клике на ваш `thead` с помощью `js` дайте атрибут `display:table-row-group`. Вот и всё. Если хотите - могу набросать пример на `jquery`

Comment: @Klimenkomud увы от табличной верстки не могу отказаться так как она напрямую прикреплена к VueJS. Было бы интересно узнать, как можно реализовать слайдер именно с таблицей, JQuery отлично должен справляться с анимацией, было бы здорово если показали как это можно реализовать на моем примере. Не очень знаю jquery в этом плане)

Comment: почему у вас структура таблицы такая странная.. Лучше ведь расположить каждый спойлер под его header'ом. Или раскрываться должны все спойлеры сразу?

Comment: Простите, я не заметил сразу.. У вас там где "Microsoft" не всё закрыто

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я запутался с вашей структурой таблицы и решил сделать пример на похожей но упрощенной. Если не разберетесь задавайте вопросы.

```js
$("thead").on("click", function() {
  t = $(this).parent("table").find("tbody").eq($(this).index($("thead")));
  if (t.css('display') == 'block') {
    t.css("display", "none");
  } else {
    t.css("display", "block");
  }
});
```

```css
.maintable tbody {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="maintable">
  <thead>
    <th class="title_team" style="font-size:14pt; padding: 20px 20px; background-color: #002C5E; color:white">Microsoft Office</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody><tr><td>Spoiler 1</td></tr></tbody>

  <thead>
    <th class="title_team" style="font-size:14pt; padding: 20px 20px; background-color: #002C5E; color:white">Microsoft Office</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody><tr><td>Spoiler 2</td></tr></tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: А как можно реализовать закрытие спойлера по такому же принципу когда он будучи открыт? То есть для каждого открытого.

Comment: @Oleg Severnuy обновил ответ.